# Working with a BQ4285 RTC from Texas Instruments

Tags: arduino, embedded, rtc

I recently acquired a BQ4285 Real-Time Clock manufactured by Texas Instruments... And I have one major problem! I have little idea how to use it.

I am trying to connect it to an Arduino Mega 2560, and I am struggling to do it on my own, and unfortunately, there is little information about this specific RTC on the web other than the datasheet, which is really quite unhelpful for someone who knows very little about working with RTCs.

Is there anyone here who has experience working with RTCs or who knows enough about them to be able to help me become familiar with them?

Specifically, I would like to know the steps involved in programming them (basically, set the time, date, month, etc.), and the steps involved in reading the data from them.

For more information, the product page from Texas Instruments can be found [here](http://www.ti.com/product/bq4285).

Comment: Step 1: Find existing code for another RTC, e.g. DS1302. Step 2: Adapt the code for the new device.

Comment: As said in comments, the DS1307 is used a lot and there are even more examples on the internet. If you want to receive another free sample you can also register at microchip or linear. Microchip delivers very fast (like TI) and linear also delivers (but it takes around 1 a 2 weeks). The Microchip Real Time Counter which is almost similar to DS1307 and BQ32000:
- MCP7940N-I/P It's an DIP package so easy solderable and there is a lot of example code available. Microchip even made some paper on how to migrate from ds1307 to mcp7940 Search for: Maxim DS1307 to MCP7940N Migration

Comment: I wish people would actually answer the question instead of just telling us to do something else. I also have some of these that I got as free samples that I would like to use in my arduino projects and I don't care if they require a lot of I/O lines or if there are cheap friendly boards. Given that these RTC chips have been around forever, I can't believe there isn't more information available on how to use them.

Answer (score 3):

The device you've come across (presumably from an old PC motherboard or similar?) is likely to be a poor choice for interfacing to an Arduino from a practical point of view. It's designed to interface to a microprocessor with an external data bus and after a quick look at the data sheet you'd need to use 8 I/O lines for address / data information and at least 4 others to clock data in and out of it.

While it may be an interesting experiment if you're not comfortable with its operation you might be better to looking for a device such as the DS1307 on e-bay for a few dollars. Many come on small PCBs with a backup battery and crystal in place and are in an Arduino-friendly format.

Devices like those only require a couple of I/O lines and there are many libraries and examples already available. For example see [DS1307 RTC With Arduino](http://blog.the-jedi.co.uk/2013/07/09/ds1307-rtc-with-arduino/).

Comment: I actually requested a free sample of this device from TI, so there aren't any losses if it is not suitable for Arduino projects, and I was just playing around with it anyway, trying to get a better understanding of how RTCs work. I was just looking on eBay at the suggested DS1307 RTCs and they look promising, so thanks for that suggestion.